# Why does not delete data in rest api

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on rest api. I got error while delete data by id. All code is complete but don't know why postman fire error. I can map two table with unidirectional mapping using hibernate.

Here down is error in postman:

> "message": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.http.HttpStatus> com.rest.RestApiPojo.Controller.PojoController.deleteAddressPerson(com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Person,java.lang.Integer)"

Here down is my code:

**Entity**

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer person_id;
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private Address address;

    // getter setter
}

@Table(name = "address_master")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer address_id;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    // getter setter
}
```

**SeviceImpl**

```
@Override
public void deleteAddressPerson(Integer personId) {
    personRepo.deleteById(personId);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dltpersonaddress/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteAddressPerson(@RequestBody Person person, @PathVariable Integer personId)
{
    pojoService.deleteAddressPerson(personId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@RequestBody Person person` parameter in `deleteAddressPerson` (in your Controller), do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unused `@RequestBody Person person` parameter in your controller method.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/dltpersonaddress/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteAddressPerson(@RequestBody Person person, @PathVariable Integer personId)
{
    pojoService.deleteAddressPerson(personId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The error message explains that this param is obligatory, and requests without it wont be processed.

Remove the param to solve the issue.